# Override 3rd party package Pod values

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I need to modify a [flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/pusher_client) which is made with swift.
So I forked the package, openend Xcode and started editing in `Pods/Pods`.
Basically I just have to change 2 variables in `Constants`.
But when I refernce my fork in my flutter packages the changes I made aren't there.

Can anyone help me with this? I am sure there is a way to modify the code.

Also run
`flutter clean`, removed `Podfile.lock` and Pods folder, run `flutter pub get` and `pod install`.

Thanks for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Every modification in Pods is just temporary, when you install pods again, that change disappears, because it installs remote pods again.
You have to fork PusherSwift cocoapod and make changes there. And of course use your version in Podfile.

Update 1:

1. fork https://github.com/pusher/pusher-websocket-swift, because what I understand you want to modify file inside. (Constants.swift)
2. put `pod 'PusherSwift', :git => 'urlToYourRepo.git', :branch => 'yourBranch'` to podfile

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you be more specific? I have no experience with swift or pods. What exactly to clone and where to put it? Also where do I reference my edited code?